# Put a green dot or red dot to show user is online or not

Tags: php, css

I have the following code to display users' images. But I would like to differentiate the images appearance with a green dot on them showing user is online and orange showing user was seen (say 15 mins ago) and red showing user is offline. Using CSS.

Now the code in a nutsell

```
//Get timing details
//get image details
//get user details

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  if($user_online){
    //show user modified image using CSS
    //image with green dot on it

  }else if($user_was_last_seen_15) {
    //show user modified image using CSS
    //image with orange dot on it

  }else {
    //show user modified image using CSS
    //image with red dot on it
  }

}
```

Comment: you might look into storing something like a cookie to see if the cookie is still there then use a green one, if the cookie is gone, then he was last seen whenever the last time a cookie session was found for that user. I don't know enough about cookie to help you with that though.

Comment: What is your actual question? I think we need to be seeing your CSS code instead of your PHP here. Have you made any attempt at this?

Comment: This will be possible in CSS 10. Conditions using only CSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a class to the container of the image (`.status` in the example below) to indicate the status (online / offline). Then you can add an empty element in the container (fixed or with javascript) and use that to display the dots:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container .status {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;    // position you want
  left: 0:   // position you want
}
.container.offline .status {
  background: url(/your/dot/image/offline);
}
.container.online .status {
  background: url(/your/dot/image/online);
}
```

The code is probably not complete (you might need a `z-index`), but it´s a start. Also note that you don´t need the `.container` class, that's just to indicate the parent element and I have only used 2 statuses instead of 3.

Answer (score 16):

Seams that the answer is directly in the code of this page actually 
take a look top right, you'll see next to your profil picture something really similar to what you aim to do

Here's a bunch of code :

```css
.logged-in {
  color: green;
}

.logged-out {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="logged-in">●</span>
<span class="logged-out">●</span>
```

Aiming to be useful, I leave it to you to implement it in your use case,

Cheers

Comment: Nice and simple :)

Comment: Thanks, but that come from the code of this page 

Answer (score 2):

Have a div surround the image and put a class on it, say

```
<div class="user-avatar">
  <img src="users-avatar-here.jpg" />
  <!-- if else statement here -->
  <img src="green.jpg" class="status" />
  <!-- else -->
  <img src="red.jpg" class="status" />
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.user-avatar {
  position: relative
}

.status {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Green dot using SVG (can be placed directly to HTML and styled with CSS)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="#00FF00" d="m2 12a10 10 0 1 1 10 10 10 10 0 0 1 -10-10z"/></svg>
```

Green dot using CSS:

```css
.green-dot {  /* use on empty div */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #00FF00;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

modify 2 images with paint and place green dot and red dot on each one then  use greendot image when user is online and red one when user is offline

Comment: This has to be done programmatically as users upload their own images.